# Filter doesnt work on long string addresses

Tags: javascript

I am trying to build a little filtering tool in lightening web components and I can filter perfectly by the name but it fails if I try filtering by the billing address(state, city or country)

Returned API data looks like this

```
[
    {
        "Id": "001IY000002QarYYAS",
        "Name": "Bertha Lee",
        "BillingStreet": "22 Fifo Street",
        "BillingCity": "Sunshine",
        "BillingCountry": "Australia"
    },
    {
        "Id": "001IY000002QV8nYAG",
        "Name": "Sample Account for Entitlements"
    },
    {
        "Id": "001IY000002QV8bYAG",
        "Name": "Edge Communications",
        "BillingStreet": "312 Constitution Place\nAustin, TX 78767\nUSA",
        "BillingCity": "Austin"
    },
    {
        "Id": "001IY000002QV8cYAG",
        "Name": "Burlington Textiles Corp of America",
        "BillingStreet": "525 S. Lexington Ave",
        "BillingCity": "Burlington",
        "BillingCountry": "USA"
    },
    {
        "Id": "001IY000002QV8dYAG",
        "Name": "Pyramid Construction Inc.",
        "BillingStreet": "2 Place Jussieu",
        "BillingCity": "Paris",
        "BillingCountry": "France"
    },
    {
        "Id": "001IY000002QV8eYAG",
        "Name": "Dickenson plc",
        "BillingStreet": "1301 Hoch Drive",
        "BillingCity": "Lawrence",
        "BillingCountry": "USA"
    },
    {
        "Id": "001IY000002QV8fYAG",
        "Name": "Grand Hotels & Resorts Ltd",
        "BillingStreet": "2334 N. Michigan Avenue, Suite 1500\nChicago, IL 60601, USA",
        "BillingCity": "Chicago"
    },
    {
        "Id": "001IY000002QV8gYAG",
        "Name": "United Oil & Gas Corp.",
        "BillingStreet": "1301 Avenue of the Americas \nNew York, NY 10019\nUSA",
        "BillingCity": "New York"
    },
    {
        "Id": "001IY000002QV8hYAG",
        "Name": "Express Logistics and Transport",
        "BillingStreet": "620 SW 5th Avenue Suite 400\nPortland, Oregon 97204\nUnited States",
        "BillingCity": "Portland"
    },
    {
        "Id": "001IY000002QV8iYAG",
        "Name": "University of Arizona",
        "BillingStreet": "888 N Euclid \nHallis Center, Room 501\nTucson, AZ 85721\nUnited States",
        "BillingCity": "Tucson"
    }
]
```

```
Javascript code to manipulate data and push to my html

export default class Accountsfilter extends LightningElement {

    availableAccounts;
    error;
    columns = columns;
    searchString;
    initialRecords;


    @wire( fetchAccounts )  
    wiredAccount( { error, data } ) {

        if ( data ) {

          

            this.availableAccounts = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
            console.log(this.availableAccounts);
            this.initialRecords = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
            this.error = undefined;

        } else if ( error ) {

            this.error = error;
            this.availableAccounts = undefined;

        }

    }

   

    
    handleSearch( event ) {

       
        const searchKey = event?.target?.value.toLowerCase();

        console.log(searchKey)
       
       

        if ( searchKey ) {

            console.log(searchKey)

           this.availableAccounts = this.initialRecords;
           
            
            if ( this.availableAccounts ) {

              


                let recs = []

                recs.concat(this.availableAccounts.filter(x => x?.BillingCity.toLowerCase().includes(searchKey)))

         
                
                this.availableAccounts = recs

             }
 
        }  else {

            this.availableAccounts = this.initialRecords;

        }        

    }

}
```

In the code above I use billing city and it fails. I wanna be able to filter using billingstreet, city and country

Comment: Not all items on the list have property BillingCity so you cannot call .toLowerCase() on it directly

Comment: `x.billingCity?.toLowerCase().includes(searchKey)` instead of `x?.BillingCity.toLowerCase().includes(searchKey)`

Comment: @PeterSeliger thanks. That works perfectly. I was only optional chaining the first object.